# Need to hide html input inside for loop

Tags: javascript, twig, swig-template

I am using swig/twig to create a loop inside a select statement. I am doing this because I need a value from a variable as you will see. I have it so the values are all good but When I  load the page it shows all but the top option in the loop outside the select. Like right below it. Here is my loop:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Asset" name="asset" data-live-search="true">
 {%  for asset in assets  %}
  <option value="{{ asset.assetNumber }}">{{ asset.model }} | {{ asset.assetNumber }}</option>
  <input type="hidden" name="assetID" value="{{asset.id}}">
 {% endfor %}
</select>
```

I can have unlimited things in the array but still only the 1 will be in the selector. This causes it so I can't use the selector for what I need to and defeats the whole page since it is based off that value.

I also tried `<button value="{{asset.id}}"></button>` but it would not show up in console when I logged out the variable in the post route. How can I get it to show up in the post route but not affect my selector?

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Asset" name="assignSel" data-
 live-search="true">
 {%  for assign in assigns  %}
   <option name="assign" value="{{ assign.id }}">{{ assign.subuser }} | {{ 
  assign.asset.num }}</option>
  <input type="hidden" name="outdate" value="{{ assign.checkoutDate }}"/>
 {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Comment: You can't have `<input>` elements inside a `<select>` element. If you're trying to associate hidden data with each `<option>` use a `data-` attribute.

Comment: How would I access that in my route? Same way `req.body.what?`

Comment: Okay  so I did `data-id={{ asset.id }}` and I can't seem to even see it in my `req.body` I put it inside the `option` tag

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments use a data attribute, but you still need some javascript to assign the data value to your form

<kbd>javascript</kbd>

```
$('select[name="asset"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[name="assetID"]').val($('option:selected', this).data('asset-id'));
    console.log($('input[name="assetID"]').val());
});
```

<kbd>twig</kbd>

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" title="Asset" name="asset" data-live-search="true">
{% for asset in assets %}
     <option value="{{ asset.assetNumber }}" data-asset-id="{{ asset.id }}">{{ asset.model }} | {{ asset.assetNumber }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="assetID" value="">
```

Comment: Are you able to insert that into node.js code? I included query module and not working. I found it need jsdom and included that. Used the example config code without luck. How can I put normal JS in node code?